Find Window by Title and Remove ControlBox with Powershell
I want to remove the ControlBox (close, minimize, maximize buttons) from a window whose title I know. I can get the process involved with Get-Process, but don't know how to access the window settings.

How about run in FullScreen or Focused mode?

Get-Processdoesn't expose such methods to PowerShell.
You would have to revert to C# instead, which luckily, can be run from PowerShell without compiling.
I've used similar techniques in C# before to handle windows, but don't actually know the language that well myself.
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class HandleWindows
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);

    const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    const uint MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;

    public static void DisableClose(string windowTitle)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, windowTitle);
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, false);
            if (hSystemMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                EnableMenuItem(hSystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED);
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

[HandleWindows]::DisableClose("Your Window Title")


Your Window Title can use $Host.UI.RAWUI.WindowTitle

Is that good or bad? :)

Thanks for your script. I have tested, worked both on PWSH and PowerShell.  Perhaps you can equip it for Windows Terminal too.  Because don't worked if PWSH/PowerShell opened in WT.

That seems to be a console issue and not a PowerShell issue. Try to ask about it at GitHub - Terminal

Thank you very much, this looks very promising. I will give this a spin in the next couple of days, although another commenter has already tried it and seen it work so I'm going to mark this as solved.
